# fixing lucene 4.1/solr corrupted index

Tags: solr, lucene

My Lucene index - built with Solr using Lucene4.1 - is, I think, corrupted. Upon trying to read the index using the following code I get `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No such core: collection1` exception:

```
File configFile = new File(cacheFolder + File.separator + "solr.xml");
CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(cacheFolder, configFile);
SolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "collection1");
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("q", idFieldName + ":" + ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(queryId));
params.set("fl",idFieldName+","+valueFieldName);

QueryResponse response = server.query(params)
```

I used "checkindex" util to check the integrity of the index and it seems not able to perform the task by throwing the following error:

```
Opening index @ /....../solrindex_cache/zookeeper/solr/collection1/data/index

ERROR: could not read any segments file in directory
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /....../solrindex_cache/zookeeper/solr/collection1/data/index/segments_b5tb (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:223)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:285)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:347)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:783)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:630)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:343)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.checkIndex(CheckIndex.java:383)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.main(CheckIndex.java:1777)
```

The file `segments_b5tb` that index checker is looking for is indeed missing in the index folder. The only file that looks similar is `segments.gen`.

Is there any way to diagnose what has gone wrong and if possible, by all means to fix it as it took me 2 weeks to build this index...

Many many thanks for your kind advice!

Comment: ADD: by messing with it I think it just get worse: As the index was probably corrupt, when I was testing it again it seems to have re-created the "segment.gen" file and also re-creating those segment files (i.e., si, tip, doc, fdx etc files). I then quit the program immediately just to avoid all segement files being lost. But now it seems that the index is completely detached from those segment files, even though are physically there. I guess this is even more complicated, but is there any way to fix this at all?

Comment: Did you try to run the [fixIndex](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html#fixIndex%28org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.Status%29) method of CheckIndex?

Answer (score 1):

If the segments.gen file is the *only* file you see, you are likely out of luck, but otherwise, you can try using [`CheckIndex`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html) to check for errors, and repair the index.  Since the tool fixes the index by removing problematic segments, there may cerainly be some lost data as a result.

Comment: Thanks. No, there are segments.gen and also lots of other "si, tip, doc, fdx" files. But the file that CheckIndex is complaining about is missing, i.e., "segments_b5tb", and because of this, CheckIndex cannot continue but throws out the above error message and exits.